# prove that $O^{P^{'}}(G)=P^{G}=P[P,G]$.

Tags: finite-groups

suppose that $G$ is finite group and $p$ is prime number.prove that if $P$ is a $p$-sylow subgroup of $G$ then $O^{p^{'}}(G)=P^{G}=P[P,G]$ which $P^{G}$ is normal closure of $P$ in $G$ .

any hint or guidance or references to study will be great,thanks.

Comment: What is $\;\mathcal O^{P'}(G)\;$ ? I know the $\;p$-residual subgroup $\;\mathcal O^p(G)\;$ , but that...

Comment: $p^{'}$ means  prime numbers except $p$!

Comment: So the $\;p'$- residual of $\;G\;$ ? It's just that you wrote capital $\;P'\;$ , not $\;p'\;$ ....

Comment: sorry,I edit it now!